# asp.net 2 applications on localhost, separate port CORS issue

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that is running on one port, in the WebApiConfig I have this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")); // Enable CORS globally

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Web API configuration and services
        var formatters = config.Formatters;
        var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;

        jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")); // Allow xml only when text/html is specified
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); // Make json return as camel case
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; // Ignore loops
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None; // Preserve

        formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter); // Remove xml formatting
    }
}
```

As you can see, I enable CORS from anyone, anywhere.
I also have in my **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** set this up in my GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method:

```
var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(allowedOrigin))
{
    allowedOrigin = "*";
}
```

My second application is a SPA using angular JS. Most of the time it works, but every so often I get this error:

> > XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54326/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:52475' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.

I read somewhere that I have to configure angular $http requests, so I added this to the app config:

```
// CORS stuff
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
```

Not really sure what it is doing, but anyway this has not solved the issue.
Does anyone know what is causing this problem and how to resolve it?